# Microsoft Bot returns error on facebook for HeroCard

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Created a bot using C# and sending herocard with buttons, it works fine with webchat and emulator but on facebook. I'm getting the below error whenever I send the message with attachment to facebook.

```
SendActivityToUserAsync FAILED: 
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Web url cannot be empty for url type button",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 2018041,
        "fbtrace_id": "C0s4Cxs3g+s"
    }
}
```

Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'

//code for the attachment.

```
var heroCard = new HeroCard
{
    // title of the card  
    Title = "",
    //subtitle of the card  
    Subtitle = "",
    // list of buttons   
    Buttons = new List<CardAction> {
        new CardAction() {
            Title = "Show my calendar",
            Text = "Show my calendar",
            Type = ActionTypes.ImBack
        },
        new CardAction() {
            Title = "Show my day",
            Text = "Show my day",
            Type = ActionTypes.ImBack
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `Value` field in your card actions.  The following code works. You need the value field to provide the "value"(for lack of better word) for your ImBack

```
var heroCard = new HeroCard
{
    // title of the card  
    Title = "",
    //subtitle of the card  
    Subtitle = "",
    // list of buttons   
    Buttons = new List<CardAction> {
        new CardAction() {
            Title = "Show my calendar",
            Text = "Show my calendar",
            Type = ActionTypes.ImBack,
            Value = "123"

        },
        new CardAction() {
            Title = "Show my day",
            Text = "Show my day",
            Type = ActionTypes.ImBack,
            Value = "456"
        }
    }
};
```